# C++ Passing multiple arguments in one argument

Tags: c++, function, arguments, c-preprocessor

This may sound confusing, but how can you pass MULTIPLE ARGUMENTS in one ARGUMENT.

What I've tried is the following:

```
#define CALL(v, look, param, expect) v(param){look(expect);}
```

Example when using it (Doesn't work):

```
void CALL(InitD3D, engine->InitD3D, (HWND hWnd, bool windowed), (hWnd, windowed))

// Which should give(i want it to):
// void InitD3D(HWND hWnd, bool windowed){engine->InitD3D(hWnd, windowed);}
// But it may give: InitD3D((HWND hWnd, bool windowed)){engine->InitD3D((hWnd, windowed));}
// Or something similar or not...
```

So is basic words, how can i pass multiple arguments in one argument, without screwing it up...

Thank You

Comment: What are you actually trying to do that requires this? There's probably a better way to do it...

Comment: Fixed it, theres something called: __VA_ARGS__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define CALL(v, look, param, expect) v param {look expect;}

namespace foo {
  void bob(int x, int y) {}
}
CALL(void bob, foo::bob, (int x, int y), (x,y))

int main() {
  bob(7,2);
}
```

I would advise against this technique.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to pass more than one argument in is to use a structure.

Example:

```
typedef struct{
    int arg1;
    std::string arg2;
    int arg3;
} fn_args;

void bob( fn_args a )
{
   //access them using a.arg1, a.arg2, etc.
}
```

EDIT: You mentioned VA_ARGS. That is used when the number of arguments you want to pass in is variable. You can usually solve most problems without needing to use VA_ARGS.

Another technique you might want to look at is called the [Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html), which is more about not caring which order the function arguments are passed in. Since its not entirely clear what you're trying to do here, I've given you a few possible approaches.